# Using Promise.all to create map

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise

```
I have the following list = ["yellow", "blue", "red"]
```

I want to create a map, while with await and promiseAll while using the entries as the map key, and the function result as the value.

e.g:

```
async function concatStr(color): Promise<String> {
    return color + "dosomthing"
}

and the map will be:
{
  "yellow": "yellowdosomething",
  "blue": "bluedosomething",
  "red": "reddosomething"
}
```

I believe that I need to use yield , but not sure how to do it

Comment: That's not a map, that's an object?

Comment: That's not a `Map`, that's a plain object.

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(await Promise.all(list.map(async color => [color, await concatStr(color)]))`? No, don't use `yield`.